# Office javascript api: context.application undefined

Tags: office-js

We've created a plugin which is using the context.application.createDocument function. This works fine with the beta libs: https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/beta/hosted/office.js

Unfortunately if I change to https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/Office.js context.application == undefined.

In the manifest I'm requiring version 1.3:

```
<Requirements>
    <Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.3">
      <Set Name="WordApi" MinVersion="1.3" />
    </Sets>
  </Requirements>
```

According to the documentation the function should be available in version 1.3 (https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/master/reference/requirement-sets/word-api-requirement-sets.md#whats-new-in-word-javascript-api-13)

I can't continue using the beta libs, because the plugin is rejected for that reason when submitting it to the store.

Comment: Could you provide the code where you are getting the context.application is undefined error?